# inserting rows using list excel

Tags: excel, vba

i am trying to write code which enables me to insert X number of rows in an excel Based on a list. I could figure out inserting X number of rows through code but cannot wrap my head around how to work it in accordance to a list. To elaborate i have a sheet 1 with column A having some unique values till 100 rows, and i have another lists which says among these unique values how much of rows needs to be inserted. Now i need a code which run through the lists and insert rows in sheet 1. Till now i have come up with following code.

```
  Sub test()
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

Dim k As Long, t As Range
k = InputBox("No. rows to be inserted")
Set t = Range("A2")
Do
Range(t.Offset(1, 0), t.Offset(k, 0)).EntireRow.Insert
Set t = Cells(t.Row + k + 1, 1)
If t.Offset(1, 0) = "" Then Exit Do
Loop
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

End Sub
```

However this is a very rigid code to my usage. How do i work this in accordance to a list.

Comment: please add examples of "lists" as well as of both "before" and "after" scenarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an index/match on your list of unique values to get how many rows to insert. Below would get the number of rows to insert for k.

```
...
Dim k As Long, t As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Do
     Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet2")
     k = WorksheetFunction.Index(ws.Range("B:B"), WorksheetFunction.Match(t.Value, ws.Range("A:A"), 0))
...
```

Note: where Sheet2 is your list of unique values with # of rows to insert. Range A:A is the unique values and Range B:B is the number of rows.

The problem with this is index... if there isn't a match in the lookup list, you will get a VBA error. A helper column in Sheet1 with `=IFERROR([index/match function],0)` would be better, or you can just ignore the errors with `On Error Resume Next`.

Comment: Hey thanks, I have got the idea of how this is intended to be done. After altering the code however i am unable to reach to the desired result. Sheet 1 have uniques where line to be inserted, sheet 2 have same uniques with number of rows to be inserted.